# Remove any style jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using jquery tabs but when one is active I get this ugly border: see image

[image: Border]

I have tried to give the tab a class and style it (as you can see its green with blue text) but nothing helped to remove this.

But for some reason it wont help

```
$(function() {
    $( "#more" ).tabs();
});
```

```
<div id="more">
      <ul id="cats">
        <li><a href="#alles">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#web">Websites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#apps">Apps</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I can style anything but that blue border wont go away

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS.

```
#more a
{  
    outline: none;  
}
```

As others have mentioned this affects accessibility for some users, but you can apply an alternative style to your tabs to retain that accessibility... for example, change the font colour on focus:

```
#more a:focus
{  
    color: #f00;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the browser's outline border.
You can remove it with CSS, with `outline:none;` in your tabs.

But remember outlines are part of accessibility, since it shows the user where his 'tab' is. So a user who can't use the mouse would be clueless where he is.

Comment: mhh good point, but I could make a active class and add that right?

Answer (score 0):

increase the height or padding of your green background bar, and simply change the outline color to match that green color.  This way accessibility is not taken away, and you still get a clean look.